# Using script within ASPX page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

so I have this code within an ASPX page. I am trying to use it within a text box in the same page, but no success. However, I can use the script within a text box in my master page? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

<script src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtStationName').autocomplete({
            source: 'StationHandler.ashx'
        });
    });
</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtStationName" runat="server">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: the textbox that generated by the asp is different id, try to look into browser console to check what is the real id, it usually generate like  (your masterpagename)_txtstationname or use `$('input[id$="txtStationName"]')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `<asp:TextBox ID="txtStationName" runat="server">` is server side component. .NET will append certain value with your ID. There might be two solution for this condition.

1) You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to make the generated IDs consistent

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" 
ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

<script src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtStationName').autocomplete({
            source: 'StationHandler.ashx'
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStationName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:TextBox>
```

2) Or find the exact ID generated on DOM from developer console and use js on that element.

Answer (score 2):

The ID of your textbox will be changed by the asp.net compiler. To prevent this you'll want to do:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStationName" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static">

</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try with classname in your code

```
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="uniquetxtStationName" ID="txtStationName" runat="server">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

and use it in script :

```
$('.uniquetxtStationName').autocomplete({
    source: 'StationHandler.ashx'
});
```

Reason behind this :  aspx will update all your ID of server tag, so you cant use actual ID of your tag in to javascript function directly.

Answer (score 0):

you have two option to work one is id another is class

`<asp:TextBox CssClass="clstext" ID="txtauto" runat="server">
 </asp:TextBox>`

for class you use

```
$('.clstext').autocomplete({
source: 'StationHandler.ashx'
```

});

if you use id then

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStationName" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static">
```

```
$('.txtStationName').autocomplete({
source: 'StationHandler.ashx'
});
```